# live click event of an image is not supported in ie6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I am retriving this content from ajax

```
<div id="content">
click on image to close<img id="img_id">
</div>
```

jQuery code to close div:

```
$("#img_id").live('click',function(){
    $("#content").slideUp('fast');
});
```

Once I click on image div closes. But in IE6 nothing happens. I don't know why IE6 doesn't take live click event, or if the problem is with image id.

Once image clicked (live click event not triggered in IE6) What would be the reason?

Comment: Which version of jQuery, and what `DOCTYPE` are you using?

Comment: I'm glad my answer answered your question, but out of curiousity, which was it? #1? #2? Something in the example that helped with some other issue with the code you were using? Just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works in simple tests (see below), even with IE6, so we're looking at something specific to your page.

Thoughts:

1) IE, and particularly IE6, has issues [mixing together namespaces](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/by-any-other-name-would-smell-as-sweet.html), do you have **anything** on the page with the name "content" or "img_id" other than the above? Any global variables? The `name` attribute on a field?

2) Are you absolutely sure the code setting up the `live` handler *is* being executed on IE? IE has issues with some syntax quirks that some other browsers don't have (for instance, trailing commas in object literals), so you need to be sure the script is parsing correctly.

---

Simple test, with no DOCTYPE (that doesn't seem to make a difference one way or the other), no HTML5 shim, etc.:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>
</html>​
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

  display("Setting live handler");
  $("#img_id").live('click',function(){
    $("#content").slideUp('fast');
  });

  display("Loading content from http://jsbin.com/ihuki3...");
  $("#container").load("http://jsbin.com/ihuki3", function(xhr, statusText) {
    display("Done loading, status = " + statusText);
  });

  function display(msg) {
    $("<p/>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }
});​
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ifubi5/5) * [Live copy with DOCTYPE](http://jsbin.com/ifubi5/6)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I assume your image has src set?